# Sed remove string until match in Linux

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I am new to Linux command.

I have below content in the tst.out file. I want to remove all the row string starting till third `'|'`:

```
MIN AU 09/15/22 C39.5 Equit|0|75|MIN 9 C39.50|AU|BBG018NNGHR1|
TIN AU 09/15/22 C39.9 ITY|0|75|RIN 9 D39.50|AU|BBG018NNGHR45|
CIN AU 09/15/22 C39.8 Ref|0|75|PIN 9 F39.50|AU|BBG018NNGHR66|
```

After removing of row string starting till third `'|'`, the file content should look like below:

```
MIN 9 C39.50|AU|BBG018NNGHR1|
RIN 9 D39.50|AU|BBG018NNGHR5|
PIN 9 F39.50|AU|BBG018NNGHR6|
```

Can you please tell how to achive this using `sed` command in Linux ?
Thanks!

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/ Please read the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command), and [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on asking good questions that get good answers.

Comment: I still don't see that you showed what you tried.

Comment: Just because - don't forget awk. `$: awk -F\| '{print $4"|"$5"|"$6"|"}' tst.out`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/([^|]*\|){3}//' input_file
MIN 9 C39.50|AU|BBG018NNGHR1|
RIN 9 D39.50|AU|BBG018NNGHR45|
PIN 9 F39.50|AU|BBG018NNGHR66|
```

Comment: i tried the command but its not doing anything ..

Comment: ohh i need to create new file does it not work with the same file ?

Comment: @Andrew You can use your file as is. Just replace input_file with your file name

Comment: working now :) sorry to bother again but need one small change ..it should skip the first row and then start with second row and do the logic ...Is it possible to skip the first row with the same command ? thanks

Comment: @Andrew The number in curly braces `{3}` tells it how many rows to remove. Try changing to `1` etc

Comment: "Rows would be lines in the file. *Columns* would be the data between corresponding sets of delimiters." -- Pedantic man

Answer (score 2):

If the text have a fixed format this `sed`command will perform according to your need.

```
sed -r 's/(.*\|)(... .)/\2/' test.txt
```

Grouping and using the last match.

Not using `sed` but `cut`. Can you use cut?

```
$ cat test.txt | cut -d "|" -f 4-
MIN 9 C39.50|AU|BBG018NNGHR1|
RIN 9 D39.50|AU|BBG018NNGHR45|
PIN 9 F39.50|AU|BBG018NNGHR66|
```

Comment: i am sorry as i am going to use this sed in complex bash script, thats why i mentioned i need to use sed specifically

Answer (score 1):

Please take the time to read the guide and try a few things. Your question should ideally be *"What am I doing wrong?"* instead of *"How do I do this?"*

```
$: sed -E 's/^[^|]*[|][^|]*[|][^|]*[|](.*)/\1/' tst.out
MIN 9 C39.50|AU|BBG018NNGHR1|
RIN 9 D39.50|AU|BBG018NNGHR45|
PIN 9 F39.50|AU|BBG018NNGHR66|
```

or

```
$: sed -E 's/^(([^|]*[|]){3})(.*)/\3/' tst.out
MIN 9 C39.50|AU|BBG018NNGHR1|
RIN 9 D39.50|AU|BBG018NNGHR45|
PIN 9 F39.50|AU|BBG018NNGHR66|
```

Comment: do i need to create new file does it not work with the same file ?

Comment: It works on any files listed on the command line, or on input from stdin such as a pipe or redirection (`sed '1q' < some-file`).

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed '
s/|/\
/3;s/^.*\n//' file
MIN 9 C39.50|AU|BBG018NNGHR1|
RIN 9 D39.50|AU|BBG018NNGHR45|
PIN 9 F39.50|AU|BBG018NNGHR66|
```

Change the 3rd match of `|` to a newline, then remove everything up to and including the newline.

Or you can use the `D` command:

```
$ sed '
t
s/|/\
/3;D' file
MIN 9 C39.50|AU|BBG018NNGHR1|
RIN 9 D39.50|AU|BBG018NNGHR45|
PIN 9 F39.50|AU|BBG018NNGHR66|
```

`D` removes the newly created line and passes the remainder of the pattern space to the next cycle which triggers the conditional `t` command due to the successful `s///`, branching to the end of the script where the resulting pattern space is printed. If there is no 3rd match of `|`, then nothing will be printed.

Comment: sed: -e expression #1, char 13: unknown option to `s',   sed: can't find label for jump to `s/|/\/3'

Comment: both command throws an errors..why do you wrote them in separate line ?

Comment: Neither command should produce errors. Maybe there's a copy-paste issue? The newlines are part of the `sed` script.